# Grails createCriteria mysql IF statement

Tags: mysql, grails, if-statement, case

I'm a newbie in Grails, and I have a big problem.
I have this domain:

```
class Product{

  String name
  Integer priority
  Double quantity
}
```

I want to sort Products by priority (which **IS** 0 or 1) - desc, and then sort by quantity. In mysql I do it like this:

```
select name, IF(quantity>=1,1,0) as q from product
where ...
order by priority desc, q desc, id desc
```

There is alse CASE statement in mysql, but in Grails I don't have an idea how to create criteria for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, splix. Tnx for editing my post. I was in hurry... Sorry!

Comment: [One needs to create a custom `Order` (sql-generating) class](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/) to sort on arbitrary expression, or just go with SQL. Looks like even HQL cannot do that: `Product.executeQuery('from Product p order by (id > 100)')` fails for me with HQL syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

```
Product.createCriteria().list(){
    projection{   // 1. because you only want to getname list.
       property("name")
    }
    ge("quantity", 1) // 2. greater than or equal 1

   order("priority", "desc" ) // by default "asc"
   order("quantity", "desc" )
   order("id", "desc" )
};
```

1. Only Returns the given property in the returned results when you wrapping by "projections".

   ```
   projections {
      property("firstName")
   }
   ```
2. Where a property is greater than or equal to a particular.

   ```
    ge("balance", 1000)
   ```
3. "desc" or "asc" for descending and ascending respectively. By default, results are sorted in ascending order

[Grails Official Doc v4.0.0](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: Added. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something around below :

```
  select name,IF(quantity>=1,1,0) as q
  from product 
  where ... 
  order by IF(priority=1,0,1), q desc, id desc
```

Considering Priority 1= high 0=low

Please do required changes

Comment: Hi, Teez. Thanks for fast reply, but I obviosly didn't explain what I need. I want a Grails criteria which will do same as mysql statement above. Sorry for my bad english.